# pegar caminho da pasta

Tags: javascript, vue.js

preciso gravar o caminho de um diretório no sistema, quando o usuário clicar em um botão abrir uma janela e nessa janela ele selecionar a pasta que deseja armazenar as informações. 
Tentei fazer usando o input com type 'file' mas ele exige que seja um arquivo

Comment: Não entendi bem, você quer selecionar uma pasta local, do computador da pessoa, ou uma pasta remota, do servidor?

Comment: local, na verdade tenho uma função no servidor que vai salvar um arquivo .txt no computador do usuário, atualmente informo o local mas quero que o usuário escolha o local que ele quer salvar o arquivo.

Comment: Acho que não tem como seu código pedir isso, quem define onde salvar o download é o próprio browser.